General form of Mercer's Theorem
I stumble upon various form of this theorem, sometime with confusing wording (symmetric, vs hermitian for the kernel for instance).
Just to be sure, the correct version would apply to a self-adjoint positive operator $K:\mathcal{X}\times\mathcal{X}\mapsto\mathbb{K}$ where $\mathcal{X}$ is a compact metric space and $\mathbb{K}$ being $\mathbb{R}$ or $\mathbb{C}$.
The positiveness being: $\forall n\in\mathbb{N},\forall{(x_i,c_i)\in\mathcal{X}\times\mathbb{K}:i\in\left[\!\!\left[1,n\right]\!\!\right]},\sum_{(i,j)∈\left[\!\!\left[1,n\right]\!\!\right]^2}{K(x_i,x_j)\boldsymbol{\overline{c_i}}c_j}≥0$
Then Mercer's result would be $K(x,y)=\sum_{i\in\mathbb{N}}{\lambda_i}\boldsymbol{\overline{\Phi_i(x)}}\Phi_i(y)$ with $\Phi_i:\mathcal{X}\mapsto\mathbb{K}$ and $\lambda_i\geq0$.
(the conjugate resolving to nothing if $\mathbb{K} is \mathbb{R}$).
Is this correct?
